# What format to submit raw images in for Cloud Vision Engine

Tags: azure, vision

I'm trying to run OCR on an image by calling the Computer Vision API and passing it data but it isn't working. I've tried data in Base64 and Binary formats, neither work. What format should be to "application/octet-stream"?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure computer vision API does not support raw, it only supports these file formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/home) If you want to send RAW, you need to first convert it to one of the supported file formats.

(If you want another format, like 'raw', you can build an Azure Function, containing a one-line batch file and an existing image conversion program like ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to do the conversion for you. Then you'd be able to support a wide range of image formats.)

The way to send an image from a C# program is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp
It sends the image as an octet-stream, basically as a HTTP-form post. (The same way data would be sent if you'd submitted a form.)

Comment: Hi Realbart, thanks for your answer. By "raw" i meant the binary data rather than the "RAW" image format. I was wondering what encoding to send a JPEG or PNG in. I've tried base64 and "raw" bytes, neither work. Do you know the error?

Comment: Like I wrote in the last paragraph of my answer: as an octet-stream, just like form data. So in the body of your request.

Comment: That's what I'm doing and I just get a 400 error. Could you an example HTTP request?

Comment: @user3614104 no, sorry. I've done this a coulple of month ago using a slightly modified version of the example code.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks for your help. I got it working using the base64 encoding

Comment: I was trying to send the image in base64 format, but still getting that code 400 error